# Creating an answer line with point value in an exam

Tags: exam, points

I'm creating an exam and trying to format the answer line, and having a world of trouble with it. My ideal format is to have:

The question

Vertical space (for workings)

Then a right-aligned answer space that would look like ____________ [3]

I've tried a few random things, and am at the point of making a new "question end" command \qend. This is what I have so far:

```
    \documentclass{exam}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \pointsdroppedatright
    \bracketedpoints

    \newcommand{\qend}{\newline \hfill \rule{2cm}{0.4pt} \droppoints}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}\textbf{Basic Quiz}
    \end{center}\vspace{0.2cm}

    Name: \hrulefill \hspace{0.1cm} Date: \hrulefill
    \vspace{0.4cm}

    Answer each question completely and to the best of your ability. Show all of your workings in the space provided.
    \vspace{0.4cm}

    \begin{questions}

    \question[3] If blah, then blah. \\ Explain the effect of this logical statement in basic conversation. \vspace{2cm} \qend

    \end{questions}

    \end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this command does not work since the \rule is still left-aligned.

**I tried \par, but it puts the points on a new line, which is not what I'm looking for.**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look in the document of the [exam](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) class, you should see there is already a macro to achieve what you want : `\answerline`.

With this macro, you can also add the answer by optionnal argument and change the space allowed for answers or the length of the answer lines.

We only have to change the behaviour to add the points at the end of the lines and to remove the label of the question presents just before the line. To do that, I add `\droppoints` in `\answerline` and remove the definitions of label.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\answerline[1][{}]{%
    \par \nobreak \vskip \answerskip
    \hfill 
    \ifprintanswers
    \hbox to 0pt{\hbox to \answerlinelength{\hrulefill}\droppoints\hss}%
    \raise \answerclearance\hbox to \answerlinelength{%
        % 2016/05/10: Added \color@begingroup and \color@endgroup:
        \color@begingroup
        \CorrectChoice@Emphasis \hfil #1\hss
        \color@endgroup}%
    \else
    \hbox to \answerlinelength{\hrulefill}\droppoints%
    \fi
    \par
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

But this leave a white space glue between the line and the points due to the droppoints command. So we have to fix this also. And we have finally :

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pointsdroppedatright
\bracketedpoints


%%%%%%%  renewcommand to have \droppoints in the \answerline commands.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\droppoints{%
    \leavevmode\unskip\nobreak%\hfill
    \rlap{\hskip\rightmargin  % Defined by the list environment
        \hskip\@rightmargin % Defined by exam.cls
        \hskip-\rightpointsmargin
        \llap{\padded@point@block}%
    }% rlap
    \par
}
\renewcommand\answerline[1][{}]{%
    \par \nobreak \vskip \answerskip
    \hfill 
    \ifprintanswers
    \hbox to 0pt{\hbox to \answerlinelength{\hrulefill}\droppoints\hss}%
    \raise \answerclearance\hbox to \answerlinelength{%
        % 2016/05/10: Added \color@begingroup and \color@endgroup:
        \color@begingroup
        \CorrectChoice@Emphasis \hfil #1\hss
        \color@endgroup}%
    \else
    \hbox to \answerlinelength{\hrulefill}\droppoints%
    \fi
    \par
}
\makeatother



%\printanswers                      %To print answers
%\setlength\answerskip{2ex}         %To set the space for answers.
%\setlength\answerlinelength{1in}   %To set the length of the line.
\begin{document}

\begin{center}\textbf{Basic Quiz}
\end{center}\vspace{0.2cm}

Name: \hrulefill \hspace{0.1cm} Date: \hrulefill
\vspace{0.4cm}

Answer each question completely and to the best of your ability. Show all of your workings in the space provided.
\vspace{0.4cm}

\begin{questions}

\question[3] If blah, then blah. \\ Explain the effect of this logical statement in basic conversation.

\answerline[this is the answer]

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Final output :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is helpful. Unfortunately, I was looking for something a bit simpler, and I was able to find a suitable solution.

Comment: Please share the suitable solution you found

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, with a little tweaking. I recognize there are other solutions to this, but I was able to achieve the desired effect with this command:

```
    \newcommand{\qend}{\newline \hspace*{\fill} \makebox{\underline{\hspace{2cm}} \hspace{-1.2cm} \droppoints}}
```

Thank you for your help, and feel free to contribute if you think there is an easier solution.